# How do binary connections eliminate multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

I was reading [Neural Network with Few Multiplications](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03009v1.pdf) and I'm having trouble understanding how Binary or Ternary Connect eliminate the need for multiplication.

They explain that by stochastically sampling the weights from [-1, 0, 1], we eliminate the need to multiply and Wx can be calculated using only sign changes. However, even with weights strictly -1, 0,  and 1, how can I change the signs of x without multiplication?

eg. W = [0,1,-1] and x = [0.3, 0.2, 0.4]. Wouldn't I still need to multiply W and x to get [0, 0.2, -0.4]? Or is there some other way to change the sign more efficiently than multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  All the general-purpose processors I know of since the "early days" (say, 1970) have a machine operation to take the magnitude of one number, the sign of another, and return the result.  The data transfer happens in parallel: the arithmetic part of the operation is a single machine cycle.

Many high-level languages have this capability as a built-in function.  It often comes under a name such as "copy_sign".

Comment: Is that a definition of `general-purpose processor`? Please name three, and the respective instructions.

Comment: Alpha: CPYS; I recall that the VAX11-750 had a MOV instruction that handled sign, and the Intel 960 also had the capability.

Comment: Hm. Given Alpha's ancestry, I wouldn't have been half surprised to have overlooked or forgotten a pertaining VAX instruction (esp. from the floating point side), but find MCOM, MNEG, and MOVZ, only. The instructions for i960 seem to be _cpysre_ and _cpyrsre_ for _copy [reverse] sign extended-real_ (sic).